# Using any parabola, find $$ such that it is tangent to the line $=$.

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, tangent-line

> Using any parabola, find $c$ such that it is tangent to the line  $y=x$.

I am not sure what this question means. I thought tangent lines were straight? How can a parabola like $x^2 + x + 1$ be "tangent" to anything?

What is this problem asking me to do, and how can I do it?

This is from a question my professor admitted was a typo. It originally said, "Find $c$ such that the parabola is tangent to the line $y=x$". Since that was unsolveable, I emailed him and asked him to clarify, and he said, "feel free to work the problem with the parabola $x^2+x+1$, though any parabola you choose would do fine.."

I then asked on this website how to find $c$ such that $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ is tangent to the line  $y=x$. Nobody seemed to know what this meant either, I got downvoted and deleted the question, so I'm asking a different question now.

I have no idea what this question is even supposed to look like, so please be understanding here.

Comment: Given the line $y = x$ with slope $1$, adjust the height of any parabola, $y = x^2 + c$ will do, by increasing or decreasing $c$ until the point where the positive slope of the parabola is $1$ is also a point on the line.

Comment: @PhilH I haven't done any similar problems so I'm not sure where to begin. Could you please explain a little more specifically? Why would adjusting the height of a parabola achieve something here?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Tangency is a symmetric relation. If you’re having trouble with the idea of a parabola being tangent to a line, then reword the question to the equivalent “Find $c$ such that the line $y=x$ is tangent to the parabola ...” Of course, this still doesn’t help identify the mysterious $c$, but that’s a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ will be tangent to a line $y=mx+q$ iff the two have exactly one point in common. This amounts to saying that the equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=mx+q\implies ax^2+(b-m)x+(c-q)=0$$
has exactly one solution, i.e. in terms of the discriminant, that
$$(b-m)^2-4a(c-q)=0$$
In your case the line is just $y=x$ which makes the general formula simpler
$$(b-1)^2-4ac=0$$
hence you see that you need to find any triplet $a,b,c$ such that
$$(b-1)^2=4ac.$$
Of course there are infinitely many such triplets.

---

If, instead, you want a parabola that is tangent to a line $y=mx+q$ at certain point $(x_0,y_0)$ then indeed you can use the derivative which results in the system
$$\begin{cases}ax_0^2+bx_0+c=y_0\\
2ax_0+b=m\\
\end{cases}$$
and adding a last condition will tell you the one parabola which you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For the parabola $y = x^2$ the slope is $1$ where the derivative $2x = 1$. Hence at $x = 0.5, y = 0.25$ the slope is $1$. Hence if we raise the parabola by $0.25$ by changing it to $y = x^2 + 0.25$, we have a tangent of the line and the parabola $y = x^2 + 0.25$ at $(0.5, 0.5)$.